# On the Complement of a subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

This question was asked in 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729648.  Since I did not get any answer I am asking it here.

In an answer in Mathoverflow I see an answer but I could not understand it. May anybody help me for Understanding it. The question and its answer are:

[On the character degrees of a finite group with special structure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160427/on-the-character-degrees-of-a-finite-group-with-special-structure)

In the beginning of the answer it is stated that by transfer and a theorem of Gaschutz we see that $N$ is complemented. By Gaschutz lemma (Stellmacher Page 74) we need an abelian and normal subgroup but $N$ is not abelian by assumption. could anybody explain why $N$ has a complement? 
Alex

Comment: I think that might be a typo and what he really wanted to write is that $H$ has a complement because $|H|$ and $|G:H|=p|PSL(2,p)|$ are coprime. This follows from the theorem of Schur-Zassenhaus (which can be derived from Gaschütz' theorem I think)

Comment: But in the proof it Seems that $N$ need a complement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a finite group $G$ has an Abelian Sylow $p$-subgroup $P,$ then by transfer, we have $P \cap G^{\prime} \cap Z(G) = 1.$ Your group $N = O_{p}(N) \times H.$ Since $G/N \cong {\rm PSL}(2,p)$ it now follows that $O_{p}(N) \leq Z(G).$ Furthermore, $O_{p}(N)$ is complemented in $G$ by Gaschutz's theorem ($G$ can't have cyclic Sylow $p$-subgroups of order $p^{2},$ again by a transfer argument, since $Z(G)$ contains an element of order $p,$ which lies outside $G^{\prime}).$ The complement $K$ to $O_{p}(N)$ has $H$ as a normal subgroup, and indeed $H$ is complemented in $K$ by Schur-Zassenhaus (which I should have explicitly mentioned). A complement $C$ to $H$ in $K$ is a complement to $N$ in $G.$

Comment: l appreciate for Your help. Since I am a beginner in group theory could You let me know what is the transfer argument means and also could You introduce me a reference for it and also for the Gaschutz theorem.

Comment: Most reasonably advanced texts in finite group theory treat transfer (eg Gorenstein, Suzuki). Almost any book on cohomology of finite groups will treat Gaschutz's theorem.

Comment: Dear Professor Robinson thanks for Your helps. could you kindly help me the second use of transfer Argument. In fact I can not get this result how using the element of order $ p$ in $ Z ( G)$ which lies outside $ G' $ implies that the Sylow subgroup is not cyclic.